# Request RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

Boa noite pessoas. Sou Novo no mundo C# e estou tendo o seguinte problema ao utilizar um código C# que faz um request de autenticação utilizando RestSharp. Esse código foi gerado/exportado de um request no Postman, portanto, eu sei que o request funciona.

Não é um url local, é um request de login no meu ambiente de produção, somente alterei os parametros, url, usuário e senha.

```
using System;
using RestSharp;

                    
public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        var client = new RestClient("https://minhaurldelogin/api/v3/login/");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n  \"email\": \"meuemail@email.com.br\",\n  \"senha\": \"M1NH4C3nha\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        
        Console.WriteLine(response.ErrorException);
    }
}
```

Printando o `response.ErrorException` eu tenho seguinte erro

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_ServerCertificateValidationCallback(RemoteCertificateValidationCallback value)
   at RestSharp.Http.ConfigureWebRequest(String method, Uri url)
   at RestSharp.Http.ExecuteRequest(String httpMethod, Action`1 prepareRequest)
   at RestSharp.Http.PostPutInternal(String method)
   at RestSharp.Http.AsPost(String httpMethod)
   at RestSharp.RestClient.DoExecuteAsPost(IHttp http, String method)
   at RestSharp.RestClient.Execute(IRestRequest request, String httpMethod, Func`3 getResponse)
The action that failed was:
Demand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer
```

Eu não sei bem o que estou fazendo de errado. Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso já aconteceu comigo, esse erro não é muito claro, mas a parte que ajuda mais é essa:

> System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission The Zone of the
> assembly that failed was: MyComputer

Ou seja, você está com problema de permissão de acesso a uma zona de internet. Consegue resolver isso através de configuração, no meu caso foi adicionando uma configuração ao `web.config`. Sua aplicação parece ser um "Console Application", o que pode ser ligereiramente diferente, mas no meu caso foi resolvido adicionando ao `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
 <trust level="Full" />  <- esta linha aqui
</system.web>
```

Note que eu coloque o `<system.web` apenas para referência para identificar onde dever adicionado, já que o `<trust>` é uma tag que vai dentre da anterior.

Se para o seu código não funcionar por conta do config ser diferente, você pode ter que adicionar um atributo na sua classe ou no arquivo do "Program", que pela mensagem de erro deve estar no namespace `System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet`.